# Optimal value for make -j <value>

Tags: make, parallelism, optimization, multiprocessor

What is the optimal value of the `-j` flag for `make` ?  I know that all my source is free of errors.

Is it the number of cores?  Or the number of logical processors?

Comment: IIRC `make` will use whatever is available without using the `-j` option.  I've always used it to limit the resources being used so that my machine is still usable for other tasks while something big builds.

Comment: @ivanivan it won’t build in parallel by default, you need to use `-j` if you want parallel builds.